# Excel - Formulas inside NotBlank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

am new to Excel , I was trying a Formula to add minutes to a cell if the Cell is not blank .

**Required ::** 
Say , I have a time(3:22pm) in cell B2 ,
What I am looking for is If(B2 is not Blank then add 9 minutes to it )

**Tried :**
I was trying to use the TIME Function something like 
=(B2 + TIME(0,9,0) 
But am not able to create a formula when i put this inside an IF NOT Block .

Any help would be appreciated .
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IF(B2<>"",B2+TIME(0,9,0),"")
```

[image]